# SiS 671/771 and Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, asus-laptop, integrated-graphics

I have installed Lubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Asus K50C, that has a Silicon Integrated Systems 671/771 Graphics Adapter. It can not boot successfully without setting through GRUB `nomodeset` or `GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768`. Also the maximum supported resolution (checked with `videoinfo` on Grub's command line) is 1024x768, while the laptop supports up to 1366x768. As I have not found a valid procedure, how is it possible to install proper drivers for the SiS 671/771 on Lubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Basically, that chipset is so old and doesn't have "modern" linux source code... You can follow a handful of tutorials online to build the kernel module from source, but the source was bad to begin with and is very old so you're not going to get 1366x768 resolution, the highest resolution the driver supports is 1280*800 and that is painfully slow. Best to just leave it at 1024*768 and save your time putting in a couple extra hours of OT to save for a new(er) laptop. The first line from my favorite tip site: "The infamous SiS graphics cards are difficult to tame in Linux, unfortunately."